# Is there a way to use an object property as templateRef inside a ng-container?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a form builder but i want it's style to be customizable, so i want to create a ng-container that build the formfield according to my formconfig object, but if i try to send a property of formconfig as an templateoutlet it return the following error on console:

###### error

```
ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedViewImpl is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (core.mjs:19896:37)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.ngOnChanges (common.mjs:3951:46)
    at NgTemplateOutlet.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:2514:14)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:3524:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:3555:9)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:3506:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:3456:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:11954:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:11937:5)
    at ModalComponent_ng_template_3_Template (modal.component.html:16:20)
handleError @ core.mjs:11752
```

###### form-build.html

```html
<ng-template #input let-item="item">
    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
        <mat-label>Clearable input</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text">
        <mat-icon matSuffix svgIcon="heroicons_outline:user-circle"></mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { formConfig: formConfig }"></ng-container>

<ng-template #template let-config="formConfig">

    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="config['perguntaForm'].formFieldType" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item: config['perguntaForm']}"></ng-container>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="input" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item: config['perguntaForm']}"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

###### form-build.ts

```js
@Component({
...})
export class FormConfig {

  formConfig: any = {
    perguntaForm: {
      formFieldType:'input',
      type: 'text'
    },
}
```

the second ng-container render just fine, but the first one don't.

i tried to force the formfieldtype to be an templateref but it didn't work

```js
@Component({
...})
export class FormConfig {

  formConfig: any = {
    perguntaForm: {
      formFieldType:TemplateRef<'input'>,
      type: 'text'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it using ViewChild('input') input!:TemplateRef
then call it on the config object

```js
    @ViewChild('input') input!:TemplateRef<any>


    formConfig: any = {
        perguntaForm: {
          formFieldType: this.input,
          type: 'text'
        },
}
```